# Undefined Behavior Killed My Cat

Tags: popularity-contest

## Undefined Behavior Killed My Cat

It's well known that undefined behavior can kill your cat <sup>[citation needed]</sup>.
But can it?

### Your Task

1. Write a program that invokes undefined behavior.
2. Describe a scenario that starts with the above program being run, resulting in a [*Felis catus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat) ending its life while in your ownership, as a result of the aforementioned UB.
3. Estimate the probability for each stage in the scenario.
4. Calculate the total probability that a single run of the program would kill your cat.

### Rules

1. This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so be creative if you can.
2. This is a programming related challenge, so the chain of events should be mostly within the computer, not in the real world (of course, if has to reach the real world if that's where your cat is).
3. If you choose a language that doesn't have undefined behavior, use something similar.
4. No animals may be harmed in the production of your answer.

### Scoring

Vote count plus the scenario's total probability (which can't exceed 1).

### Example in C:

```c
main(){printf();}
```

Scenario:

1. `printf` called with garbage from the stack - undefined behavior. Probablity: 100%.
2. The first parameter happens to be the string `Your cat is ugly!`. Probablity: (1/256)<sup>17</sup> = (1.148 * 10<sup>-37</sup>)%.
3. Seeing the message, you pick up your gun and shoot your cat. Probability: 3%.
4. The cat dies. Probability: 93%.

Total probability: (3.202 * 10<sup>-39</sup>)%.

Comment: I don't really understand the calculation of the scoring. For example, why does number 3 give `3%` as probability, and number 4 give `93%`?

Comment: @ProgramFOX, The probabilities are my estimates, that's all. Note that the probability is no more than 1, so it's no more than a tie breaker.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳, Just try not to violate rule 4.

Comment: You might want to add in a stipulation that the total probability must be greater than 0.  Are there any special rules for those of us who don't own a cat?

Comment: 1) Invoke undefined behavior 2) Remain inspired by the mere fact that you could invoke undefined behavior, and live a long, happy life 3) Cat dies of old age.  Total probability: 100%

Comment: @Geobits, but the cat's death isn't "a result of the aforementioned UB".

Comment: @Oberon I'd kill myself if I couldn't come up with a *single* way to create an UB after programming for so long. Then the cat would no longer be in my possession. Invoking the UB keeps me alive, so that "... ending its life *while in your ownership* , as a result...". Ambiguous parsing FTW.

Comment: Are special hardware interfaces allowed, eg. solenoids, shotguns?

Comment: @ProgramFOX the chance that you will shoot your cat based on said message are very low (3%). The chance of it dying when shot is high (93%).

Comment: @MartinJames, Everything is allowed. Will it get you upvotes? I don't know.

Comment: I'd be more amused if someone reinterprets this to kill the `cat` command or something of that sort.

Comment: -1 I love cats. Why cats? Why not killinig vermin?

Comment: @V-x Given the uncertainty, i'm pretty sure it's related to [Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat).

Comment: That's obvious. I wanted to compensate a bit that I'm not happy about the manifestation of cat hate.

Comment: @V-X, Where's the cat hate? I want to understand how UB can kill cats, so we could fight this menacing problem and save feline lives.

Comment: @V-X The rules say that no animals may actually be harmed.  This is a clue for you that this is not to be taken seriously.  If Schrödinger had made his thought experiment using a plague-infested rat, this question would have been about a plague-infested rat.  The fact that *NIX has a command-line tool `cat` is just a serendipitous coincidence that improves the joke.

Comment: Calling `printf` without a prototype is undefined behavior, period.

Comment: "No animals may be harmed in the production of your answer." Can I at least harm a cat while testing after production?.... Gotta make sure to get those percentages right :D

Comment: @Kevin, Sorry, but cat lovers here would downvote me to death if I let you do that. Try testing it with tofu or something.

Comment: When I saw the question title in the hot network questions, I first thought this had been asked at [pets.SE] :-)

Comment: If a cat is to be eaten, Python is a solution.

Comment: Felis catus is your taxonomic nomenclature,
An endothermic quadruped, carnivorous by nature;
Your visual, olfactory, and auditory senses
Contribute to your hunting skills and natural defenses-> Sorry had to do it :-)

Comment: Simply letting a cat live wildly is undefined behavior. Chance of death is 100%. Do I win all your triangles? :D

Comment: Why is everybody struggling for a mechanism by which the felis catus dies? That's the simple part: an omnipotent being smites it. I'll leave it to everybody's imagination *why* that happens and *how* a program error my cause that situation to arise... ;-)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'll build an automatic cat feeder with a Raspberry Pi, and implement it with UB that can cause it to malfunction.

Comment: I don't get this. For this purpose, all programs with UB are fungible.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## C

Most answers to this question misinterpreted the question in that it was killing the `cat` process on a UNIX system. Here is a program which can cause the demise of a biological lifeform of the species Felis Cattus as specificed by the question.

This example runs on Windows, but it could be easily ported to most UNIX operating systems by replacing `iexplore -k` with the command to launch an installed web browser.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

int main() {
    char i; // uninitialised
    printf("Redirecting you to a website which will inform you how to properly feed your cat.");
    if (i != 42) {
         system("iexplore -k https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats+diet");
    } else {
         system("iexplore -k https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chocolate");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program pretends to provide advise about cat diet to the user.

It will start Internet Explorer and direct the user to [pets stackexchange](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) listing lots of helpful questions about how to feed cats. There is, however, a low (1/256) chance that it will send the user to [cooking stackexchange](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) instead listing tips how to prepare dishes containing chocolate, [which is **highly toxic** to cats](http://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/digestive/c_ct_chocolate_toxicity). To make matters worse, it will launch internet explorer in kiosk mode (fullscreen), which hides the address bar and is hard to escape from for a non-tech-savy user.

This clever ruse will coax the user into feeding their cat chocolate believing that it is an appropriate diet for it, thus causing them to inadvertedly kill it.

Comment: The pen is mightier than the sword! :)

Comment: This looks like the only solution so far that has any realistic chance of actually killing a cat. I am forced to upvote, although I sincerely hope no one ever actually puts it into practice.

Comment: Internet Explorer might kill your cat all by itself.

Comment: Chocolate is highly toxic to all sorts of domestic animals. (Cats, dogs, horses, etc. should *never* be fed chocolate.)  Funny how it's not only yummy but actually supposed to be really good for humans...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've chosen MSIE because it is the only browser you can reasonably expect to exist on every Windows system. I am pretty sure there must be a console command to open a website in the *users default* browser, but I was too lazy to search for it.

Comment: Just [passing the URL to ShellExecute()](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816) is sufficient.

Comment: Can you add the scenario, step by step, that kills the cat, with the probability analysis (as in the example)? As it is, this isn't a valid answer.

Comment: @ugoren I could, but I see no entertainment value in doing so.

Comment: Depending on the compiler your chances may be as low as 0 or as high as 1 - depends if the compiler uses stackguards and what kind of ;)

Comment: In addition to what @Voo said the read of uninitialized variable in C is UB (in C90 and C11 except C99 where it is a bit more complicated) so you need to calculate probability of [nasal demons](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons) killing the cat as well.

Comment: @Philipp, I'll accept the highest voted valid answer, and to be valid it has to follow the rules.

Comment: @ugoren I am a programmer, not a psychologist.

Comment: @ugoren: The probability seems straightforward enough.  Assuming that the probability distribution of 256 possible values of `char` is reasonably uniform, the odds are 1 in 256.  Chocolate is toxic to cats.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Nope.  You have to factor in the probability that the chocolate recipe will be so tasty that the greedy owner will eat it all up, with none left for poisoning kitty.  Although then maybe kitty would starve to death...

Comment: Using Internet Explorer induces undefined behaviour in ME. — sorry, had to say that.

Answer (score 89):

## Bash

[According to this](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/887), `INT_MIN % -1` may or may not be undefined *(what ???)*, and so might cause trouble for any language implemented in c/c++.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<< $((2**63%-1))
```

The `cat` will be killed early if the parent `bash` process crashes, which may or may not happen.

On my VM I get this output:

```
$ ./schroedinger.sh
./schroedinger.sh: line 3:  7805 Floating point exception(core dumped) cat <<< $((2**63/-1))
$
```

---

*(I don't really understand the scoring for this question, but here goes anyway)*

Calculate `$((2**63%-1))`.  Crash always happens on bash 4.2.25, but seems to just hang on some 3.x versions.  More uncertainty.  I could tell you the exact probability, but due to the Heisenburg uncertainty principle I would then fall down a black hole.  Or something.  So I think we can safely say they probability is approximately 42%.

Comment: shouldn't it be `cat <<< $((-2**63/-1))`? Didn't you lose the `-` sign? Even if the behavior is the same, the minimum integer should be `-`

Comment: I know the use of `<` and `<<`, but what is the purpose of `<<<`? (used google but couldn't find anything)

Comment: @klingt.net: It is called "Here Strings" - it is much more googlable... it is shortcut for `echo $((-2**63/-1)) | cat`

Comment: Ah thanks, this is really useful!

Comment: +1 for using real `cat`.

Comment: @mardavi `INT_MAX = 2^63 - 1`.  If we add 1 to `INT_MAX`, the 64bit number space wraps around and we get `INT_MIN`.  In other words in signed 64bit integer arithmetic, `2^63 == -2^63`.  I could have used `-2**63`, but preferred the terseness without the `-`, since the modular arithmetic is the same in this case.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=579622

Comment: Can you add the scenario, step by step, that kills the cat, with the probability analysis (as in the example)? As it is, this isn't a valid answer.

Comment: `INT_MIN / -1` is **always** undefined behavior in C/C++, what wasn't clear was whether `INT_MIN % -1` (modulo not division! 2^32 is not representable in 2 complement 32bit numbers, but 0 certainly is) was undefined behavior or not. According to your link they clarified that in C11 so good riddance for that.

Comment: This *hangs* my `bash` on OS X (requires Ctrl+C to kill); why is that? (Yes, undefined behaviour yadda yadda, but you'd expect this to at least just quit somehow...)

Comment: @ugoren I edited, but I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I got that behavior too on OSX.  Sorry, I don't have an answer as to why.

Comment: How can I upvote again given that the update mentions the probablity of killing the cat (42%)?

Comment: @devnull I'll do it for you ;)

Comment: @Voo `INT_MIN / -1` is not always undefined behaviour, because `INT_MIN` is allowed to be equal to `-INT_MAX`, in which case the result of the division is representable.

Comment: @hvd good point.

Comment: It's spelled Shrödinger. But +1 for reference to quantum physics!

Comment: @AnonymousPi Ja, mit zwei punkte.

Answer (score 41):

## C (sequence point)

**deadcat.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=3;
    int k=0;
    k=i+(++i);
    if (k==7)
        printf("The cat is fine. k=i+(++i) =%d\n",k);
    else
        printf("Urgent Notice: Your cat has rabies. k=i+(++i) =%d\n",k);
}
```

**Execution (or not):**

```
$ clang -w deadcat.c -o deadcat; ./deadcat
The cat is fine. k=i+(++i) =7
$ gcc deadcat.c -o deadcat; ./deadcat
Urgent Notice: Your cat has rabies. k=i+(++i) =8
```

**Scenario and probability**

Assuming that five percent of people running this program use clang for compiling C code (versus 90 percent using gcc and 5 percent using other C compilers):

```
 Probability of getting "The cat is fine."                           =  .050
 Probability of getting "Urgent Notice: Your cat has rabies."        =  .950

 Probability of reacting to "Your cat has rabies" by putting it down =  .040
 Probability of ignoring the notice                                  =  .900
 Probability of taking the cat to the vet for treatment              =  .060

 Total probability of cat living:.05 + .95 * (.90 + .06)             =  .962
 Total probability of cat dying: .95 * .04                           =  .038
 Check: Total probability of cat living or dying:                    = 1.000
```

**Explanation:**

k=i+(++i) accesses and changes "i" between sequence points.
The probability is not determinable by the program; it depends upon the
choice of compiler, which is made by the user.  "Undefined" does not
necessarily mean "random".

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the behavior with different compilers.

Comment: optimization level may also change the behavior

Comment: @ratchet freak: Yes, but I couldn't demonstrate that with this particular problem.  I tried -O0,-O1,-O2, and -O3 on a number of gcc versions ranging from gcc-4.2.3 to gcc-4.8.2, and cc-5.0 on SunOS, but all of those killed the cat.

Comment: Can you add the scenario, step by step, that kills the cat, with the probability analysis (as in the example)? As it is, this isn't a valid answer.

Comment: @ugoren: Working on that.  It's essentially the probability of the user using clang or gcc.  I can't find data on market shares but I believe clang's share isn't very big now but is increasing.  It's probably higher among Stack* members than among the general public.  So I'll just make a SWAG that it's 5 percent clang now, and that most of those use both clang and gcc.

Comment: I assumed that all the cats that were taken to the vet for treatment would live.  Probably some of those will die from catching a communicable feline disease or from veterinary malpractice.  That might change the final probabilities a little, to say .96/.04

Comment: Note that with the latest gcc that comes with XCode 5.1 this is no longer the case: gcc deadcat.c -o deadcat; ./deadcat
deadcat.c:7:10: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
    k=i+(++i);
      ~  ^
1 warning generated.
The cat is fine. k=i+(++i) = 7

Comment: @MikeLischke I think that's because gcc that comes with XCode 5.1 is actually clang/LLVM.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson No, they are different. Clang does "the right thing" without bringing up a warning even with -Wall, while gcc displays a warning.

Answer (score 39):

## C

#### Backstory

My wife inherited a cat from family.<sup>†</sup> Unfortunately, I am very allergic to animals. The cat was well past its prime and should have been euthanized even before we got it, but she could not bring herself to get rid of it due to its sentimental value. I hatched a plan to end <strike>my</strike> its suffering.

We were going on an extended vacation, but she did not want to board the cat at the veterinarian's office. She was concerned about it contracting illness or being mistreated. I created an automatic cat feeder so that we could leave it at home. I wrote the microcontroller's firmware in C. The file containing `main` looked similar to the code below.

However, my wife is also a programmer and knew my feelings towards the cat, so she insisted on a code-review before agreeing to leave it at home unattended. She had several concerns, including:

- `main` does not have a standards compliant signature (for a hosted implementation)
- `main` does not return a value
- `tempTm` is used uninitialized since `malloc` was called instead of `calloc`
- the return value of `malloc` should not be cast
- the microcontroller time may be inaccurate or roll over (similar to the Y2K or Unix time 2038 problems)
- the `elapsedTime` variable may not have sufficient range

It took a lot of convincing, but she finally agreed that theses weren't problems for various reasons (it didn't hurt that we were already late for our flight). Since there was no time for live testing, she approved the code and we went on vacation. When we returned a few weeks later, <strike>my</strike> the cat's misery was over (though as a result I've now got plenty more).

<sup>† Entirely fictitious scenario, no worries.</sup>

---

#### Code

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//#include "feedcat.h"
// contains extern void FeedCat(struct tm *);
// implemented in feedcat.c
// stub included here for demonstration only
#include <stdio.h>
// passed by pointer to avoid putting large structure on stack (which is very limited)
void FeedCat(struct tm *amPm)
{
    if(amPm->tm_hour >= 12)
        printf("Feeding cat dinner portion\n");
    else
        printf("Feeding cat breakfast portion\n");
}

// fallback value calculated based on MCU clock rate and average CPI
const uintmax_t FALLBACK_COUNTER_LIMIT = UINTMAX_MAX;

int main (void (*irqVector)(void))
{
    // small stack variables
    // seconds since last feed
    int elapsedTime = 0;
    // fallback fail-safe counter
    uintmax_t loopIterationsSinceFeed = 0;
    // last time cat was fed
    time_t lastFeedingTime;
    // current time
    time_t nowTime;

    // large struct on the heap
    // stores converted calendar time to help determine how much food to
    // dispense (morning vs. evening)
    struct tm * tempTm = (struct tm *)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));

    // assume the cat hasn't been fed for a long time (in case, for instance,
    // the feeder lost power), so make sure it's fed the first time through
    lastFeedingTime = (size_t)(-1);

    while(1)
    {
        // increment fallback counter to protect in case of time loss
        // or other anomaly
        loopIterationsSinceFeed++;

        // get current time, write into to nowTime 
        time(&nowTime);

        // calculate time since last feeding
        elapsedTime = (int)difftime(nowTime, lastFeedingTime);

        // get calendar time, write into tempTm since localtime uses an
        // internal static variable
        memcpy(&tempTm, localtime(&nowTime), sizeof(struct tm));

        // feed the cat if 12 hours have elapsed or if our fallback
        // counter reaches the limit
        if(  elapsedTime >= 12*60*60 || 
             loopIterationsSinceFeed >= FALLBACK_COUNTER_LIMIT)
        {
            // dispense food
            FeedCat(tempTm);

            // update last feeding time
            time(&lastFeedingTime);

            // reset fallback counter
            loopIterationsSinceFeed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Undefined behavior:

For those who don't want to bother finding the UB themselves:

> There's definitely local-specific, unspecified, and implementation-defined behavior in this code, but that all should work correctly. The problem is in the following lines of code:
>
>     `struct tm * tempTm  //...
>     //...
>     memcpy(&tempTm, localtime(&nowTime), sizeof(struct tm));`
>
>
>  `memcpy` overwrites the `tempTM` pointer instead of the object it points to, smashing the stack. This overwrites, in addition to other things, `elapsedTime` and `loopIterationsSinceFeed`. Here's an example run where I printed out the values:
>
>     `pre-smash  : elapsedTime=1394210441  loopIterationsSinceFeed=1
>     post-smash : elapsedTime=65          loopIterationsSinceFeed=0`

---

#### Probability of killing the cat:

- Given the constrained execution environment and build chain, the undefined behavior always occurs.
- Similarly, the undefined behavior always prevents the cat feeder from working as  intended (or rather, allows it to "work" as intended).
- If the feeder does not work, it is extremely likely the cat will die. This is not a cat that can fend for itself, and I failed to ask the neighbor to look in on it.

I estimate that the cat dies with probability **0.995**.

Comment: It's the (first) `&` in the memcpy, right?

Comment: @Score_Under Yes, let me edit the answer a little. I played around with other ways to harness undefined behavior, but most were even more obvious.

Comment: +1 for killing a cat, not `cat`.

Answer (score 33):

## bash

#### Classic version

```
cat & # This is your cat.
pkill -$RANDOM cat
```

Has the advantage of killing *all* cats in its range.

Note that the process is *stopped* immediately, so the only way to end it with a single invocation of *pkill* is to send SIGKILL (9).

Therefore:

`p(SUCCESS) = p(RANDOM == 9) = 0.0275 %`

---

#### Quantum version

```
schroedinger=/dev/null             # We'll need this guy.
heisenberg=/dev/urandom            # Also needed, for uncertainty principle.
cat $heisenberg > $schroedinger &  # Steal cat from Heisenberg and give it to Schrödinger.
felix=$!                           # Name cat for future references.
exec 2> $schroedinger              # Send all results to Schrödinger.
kill -SIGSTOP $felix               # Catch Felix and put him into a box.
if (($RANDOM & 1))                 # Flip a coin.
then kill $felix                   # Heads: Kill! Kill! Kill!
fi                                 # By now, Felix can be thought of as both alive and dead.
read -sn 1                         # Wait for somebody to open the box.
kill -SIGCONT $felix               # Let him open it.
if ps p $felix > $schroedinger     # Let Schrödinger check on Felix.
then echo The cat is alive.        # Hooray for tails!
else echo The cat is dead.         # At least, now we know.
fi                                 # This concludes the experiment.
kill -SIGKILL $felix               # Felix is no longer required.
```

Probability of killing the cat during the experiment: 50 %

Comment: +1 But it's rather more likely than that I think. SIGINT (2), SIGQUIT (3), SIGABRT (6), SIGPIPE (13) and SIGTERM (15), at least, kills it here.

Comment: @l0b0: It doesn't, at least not immediately. `cat &` attempts to read from the terminal, but can't. Any of the signals you mentioned (and a few more) will work if you send SIGCONT (18) afterwards. Also, I agree that *hanging up* and *terminating* the cat would be the same as *killing* it, but *interrupting* it doesn't seem satisfactory... :P

Comment: Undefined behavior is using a feature of a language that has been **specified** as **undefined**. That is, the language designers have purposefully left the **behavior** of some **syntactical construct** undefined in order to make implementation easier, or to indicate that the construct should never be used in any valid program. Undefined behavior usually has nothing to do with random number generation, and there is no undefined behavior being used here.

Comment: @OregonTrail: The rules say *If you choose a language that doesn't have undefined behavior, use something similar.* Bash doesn't have undefined behavior, so I used random numbers.

Comment: There's plenty of undefined behavior in bash's environment which can be used. For example, the answer by @DigitalTrauma Bash's printf also uses the system's printf which has plenty of undefined behavior.

Comment: Just explaining why I don't think I broke the rules.

Answer (score 17):

## C

Note that this only works on linux.

```
main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("skynet", "w");
  srand(time(0));
  while(rand() != rand())
    fputc(rand()%256, f);
  fclose(f);
  system("chmod +x skynet");
  system("./skynet");
}
```

1. Write random data to a file and invoke it (100%)
2. Random data happens to be the source code to skynet (1x10^-999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, aprox.)
3. Cat dies in resulting doomsday (99.999%)

Total probability: 1x10^-999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, aprox.

Comment: hmmmm, what is skynet?

Comment: Where's the undefined behavior?

Comment: @SargeBorsch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)

Comment: @ugoren I think running a file with random contents isn't really defined.

Comment: @11684, If the contents happen to be the code to skynet, an skynet's programmers know what they're doing, there's no undefined behavior.

Comment: @ugoren running a file containing random ascii characters is pretty undefined.  The issue is not what it could contain, but that we don't know ahead of time what it contains.

Answer (score 16):

## C++

Your Cat is Both Dead and Alive until you are Curious. Then you realize that there is a 0.5 probability that your Cat is Dead.

```
#ifdef WIN32
#pragma warning(disable: 4700)
#endif
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <memory>
class Cat
{
public:
    enum class State {DEAD, ALIVE};
    Cat()
    {
        int x; // Uninitialized Variable on Stack
        if (x % 2 == 0) // Is the Uninitialized Variable even? 50-50
        {
            m_dead = State::DEAD;

        }
        else
        {
            m_dead = State::ALIVE;
        }
    };
    operator State() //Check if your Cat is Dead / Alive
    {
        if (m_dead == State::DEAD)
        {
            delete this; //Boom Cat is dead
            std::cout<<"Your Curiosity killed your Cat"<<std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        return m_dead;
    }
private:
    State m_dead;
};

class Schrödinger
{
public:
    Schrödinger(size_t size):m_size(size)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cats.push_back(new Cat());
        }
    }
    ~Schrödinger()
    {
    }
    void Curiosity()
    {
        std::default_random_engine generator;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,m_size);
        if(*cats[distribution(generator)] == Cat::State::ALIVE)
        {
            std::cout<<"You Cat is alive and still kicking" <<std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Cat *> cats;
    size_t m_size;
};
int main()
{
    int size;    
    std::cout<<"How Big is Your Example Space ?";
    std::cin>>size;
    Schrödinger your(size);
    your.Curiosity();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: can you access `this->m_dead` after `delete this`?

Comment: @BryanChen: A return was missing. THank you for pointing it out :-)

Comment: `ö` doesn't seem to be a valid symbol in C++. Maybe replace it with `oe`.

Answer (score 13):

## C

Runs on Linux.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void f(char x) {
    if(sleep(1)==x) system("killall cat");
}
int main() {
    char x; // uninitialised
    system("cat /dev/urandom &");
    f(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Probability of killing the cat: 1/256 (The `sleep(1)` returns 0, so it will be killed if `x` is zero.)

As a bonus, it kills all cats currently running on your system.

---

If you hate cats so much, I present to you:

#### The Cat Centipede (Bash)

```sh
echo "Hello World"|cat|cat|cat
```

Based on the fact that, in *The Human Centipede (First Sequence)*, all three dogs of the dog centipede died, and two out of three people of the human centipede died, I estimate that the probability of killing one cat is 5/6.

Comment: Cat Centipede is truly funny

Comment: The cat centipede should be the "actual" answer.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel You're probably right, I've removed the C code. At first it was meant to be a joke, but later I realised that I could rephrase it to make it an actual answer.

Comment: You can keep your C code, I have and had nothing against it. I just though that the bash version was more suitable as an answer.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel Nah, that C code was quite stupid anyway

Comment: I didn't though so. But now you have a funny answer in bash.

Answer (score 10):

```
int foo() {}

void main() {
    int x = foo();
}
```

Reading a value of function supposed to return a value results in undefined behaviour. Now, it is obvious,<sup>[citation needed]</sup> that "Every time you reach undefined behaviour, God kills a kitty." Using this we conclude:

- Probability you reach undefined behaviour - 100%
- Probability it is your kitty which god killed - 1/200 000 000 [see why](http://answers.ask.com/science/nature/how_many_cats_are_in_the_world)
- So probability is 0.0000005%

Can be easily extended by loop to exterminate all cats in the world.

Comment: Your probability is 100 times too high (200M cats, not 2M).

Comment: I have in in percents. :)

Comment: It's in percents, and still it's 100 times too high.

Comment: You are right, I cannot read numbers anymore, apparently.

Comment: This is incorrect. UB is only invoked if the caller attempts to use the return value. Otherwise it is completely legal and well-defined to walk off the end of a function with non-void return type.

Comment: Well, this answer says otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/a/367662/1715185

Comment: @R..: @Petr: This answer is not correct. In C, according to [C99 specification, 6.9.1.12](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.". This is allowed, because before ANSI C, `void` type did not exist. C++ doesn't disallow that, therefore it's also allowed in C++.

Comment: @xfix You are right, the code I provided could potentially result to undefined behaviour, but would not as I wrote it. I added the code to satisfy the condition _value of the function call is used by the caller_.

Comment: @xfix incorrect – it's UB in C++. [see here](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2)

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript

```js
~"cat".localeCompare("dead")
  ? "Cat is dead"
  : "Cat is fine"
```

**Execution:**

- **Chrome:** Results in `"Cat is fine"`
- **Firefox:** Results in `"Cat is dead"`

**Explanation:**

> [15.5.4.9 String.prototype.localeCompare (that)](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.9)
>
> The two Strings are compared in an **implementation-defined** fashion

Quoting Glenn Randers-Pehrson, the probability is not determinable by the program; it depends upon the choice of browser, which is made by the user.

Comment: Not reproducible on FF 27. Which version are you testing on?

Comment: -1: undefined behavior and implementation-defined behavior are completely different.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ FF 28. Do not forget the `~`!

Comment: @whitequark No they aren't. It is a defined function with an undefined outcome. Ergo undefined behavior.

Comment: @GeorgeReith If we're talking about these terms in context of C: the outcome is defined by implementation. If outcome was undefined, the program could navigate to http://reddit.com instead of comparing strings and it would be legal. I suggest you consult ISO/IEC 9899:1999, section 3.4.

Comment: @whitequark I don't see any C here. As far as JavaScript is concerned [Does JavaScript have undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863430/does-javascript-have-undefined-behaviour) seems to think that implementation defined behaviour is passable.

Comment: @GeorgeReith sure. however, JavaScript terminology doesn't include "undefined behavior", and using it in spite of that is needlessly confusing (as shown by this exchange), especially if discussed sideways with C.

Comment: @whitequark nobody else is confused. A word is a word, I don't need a committee to tell me what it means.

Answer (score 6):

## Java (Garbage Collection)

Although code can invoke System.gc() is does not make sure that the Garbage Collector will collect all of the unused objects. Thus, for the following code, it's unpredictable if the cat will be killed or not.

```
public class KillTheCat {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        KillTheCat cat = new KillTheCat();
        cat = null;
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("Cat is still alive.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Cat has been killed.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The probability cannot be calculated.

Note that there's still a chance that the cat will be "revived" if there's a context switch in the GC thread after sysout and before System.exit(0) but I preferred not to cover it to keep the concept simpler.

Comment: This is no good. This code as written will nearly always print both. Better would be to add `System.out.close()` after the `System.out.println("Cat is still alive.");` line.

Comment: As far as I understand, "nearly always" matches the unpredictability aspect of the question.

Answer (score 6):

## C

If your cat's name is too long, it dies. `gets` causes cat deaths, along with other problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* Stores instances of cats. */
struct cat {
    /* 6 bytes are more than enough. */
    char name[6];

    /* Stores whether your cat is dead. */
    bool dead;
};

int main(void) {
    /* This is your cat. */
    struct cat your_cat;
    /* It lives. */
    your_cat.dead = false;
    /* Determine its name. */
    printf("Your cat name: ");
    gets(your_cat.name);

    /* Output the cat state. */
    const char *state = your_cat.dead ? "dead" : "alive";
    printf("Your cat, %s, is %s.\n", your_cat.name, state);

    return your_cat.dead;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Anybody having thought of really killing (a) `cat`?

```
[ $[ $RANDOM % 6 ] == 0 ] && rm /bin/cat || echo Meow
```

#### Probabilitiy of `cat` dying

For the probability... I guess we need to distinguish some cases:

1. **Windows user**: Probably will not be able to execute it. Chance of dying `cat`s is very low, can safely be assumed to be zero. If he's got Cygwin installed, he'll count as unix user.
2. **Unix user, running without root privileges**: Killing the `cat` will fail.
3. **Unix user, running with root privileges**: While each call will only kill `cat`s with a chance of 1/6, he will very probably repeat it until something unexpected occurs. Without loss of generality, I assume `cat` will definitely die.

Overall probability depends on how the users are mixed and is hard to determine. But we can surely say: Windows is a safe place for kittens.

#### Testing for obedience of the rules

> No animals may be harmed in the production of your answer.

This did not kill animals, the answer is approved by the *American Humane Association*.

```
$ file `which cat`
/bin/cat: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

clearly proves that `cat` is no animal (as long `file` does not know any kind of hidden file type inheritance).

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell

```
import Acme.Missiles
import System.IO.Unsafe
main = print (unsafePerformIO launchMissiles, undefined)
```

Here, we apply [`unsafePerformIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) to [an action that has observable side-effects](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-missiles-0.3/docs/Acme-Missiles.html#v:launchMissiles). That is always undefined behaviour, at least so is the order of effects. So either will the program first crash on trying to evaluate [`undefined`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:undefined) (that one, ironically, is *not* undefined behaviour: it must never yield a value that would allow the program to carry on with something else), or it will in fact incur the serious international side-effects. In that case, survival chance is [only 0.001%](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22884/2183).

Probability of killing the cat thus: 49.9995%.

Answer (score 4):

## Thue

Since the question allows for a language that doesn't have undefined behavior as long as the effect is similar, I choose Thue for its **non-determinism** in choosing which rule to execute when there are more than 1 rule which can be applied on the current state.

The program will be fed into the controller for a microwave oven, inside of which is my cat. The door to the microwave oven is closed and reinforced by a zip tie. The output of the program will decide whether the microwave oven starts to microwave the cat or not.

- If the output is 0, we will start the experiment on the effect of long exposure of microwave on live mammal (which is currently insufficiently researched).
- If the output is 1, we will just be satisfied with the fact that the cat has just lost one of its 9 lives and let it out.

---

```
i::=~0
i::=~1
::=
i
```

The probability of killing the cat is dependent on the implementation of the interpreter, but let's say it's 50%. Then the probability that the cat will die is **0.5**.

Comment: Non-determinate does not mean non-defined

Comment: @Score_Under: What is your point?

Comment: The question asks for undefined behaviour, which involves leveraging behaviour of a language which will compile and run, but has no specification as to what it should actually do. Hinging things on `Math.random()` for example is not undefined behaviour, just unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: @Score_Under: In the question `3. If you choose a language that doesn't have undefined behavior, use something similar.`

Answer (score 1):

### Java

According to [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) `java.util.Date` will have undefined behaviour. So try your luck:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class App3
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        String aliveOrDead;
        Date d = new Date(-1000,-1000,-1000);
        aliveOrDead = (d.getTime()<0)? "dead" : "alive";
        System.out.println("The cat is:" +aliveOrDead );
    }
}
```